# Absolute Galois group is topologically generated by Frobenius map clarification

Tags: galois-theory, profinite-groups

I came across the following while reading a text on elliptic curves:

For the $q$th power Frobenius morphism on an elliptic curve $E$, 
$\phi: E \rightarrow E$ given by $\phi(x,y) = (x^q, y^q)$,the absolute Galois group $Gal(\bar{\mathbb{F}_q}/ \mathbb{F}_q)$ is topologically generated by this morphism. And we have

$$ P \in E(\mathbb{F}_q) \Leftrightarrow \phi(P) = P. $$

However, I haven't been able to find a proper definition of 'topologically generated' anywhere.

It'd be great if someone could help me on this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That the Galois group is topologically generated by the Frobenius automorphism, means that the *closure* of the subgroup generated by this automorphism is the full Galois group.

Comment: Thank you. Could you maybe provide a source for this? Also, the 'if and only if' on the post follows only from the fact that the Frobenius morphism fixes $\mathbb{F}_q$, right?

Comment: To the latter; yes, because $\Bbb{F}_q$ is precisely the fixed field of the Frobenius morphism.

Comment: As for a source;  if you consider Wikipedia a reliable source, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_set_of_a_group), specifically the last line before 'Contents'.